# How make all ExtJS wedgit RTL?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, right-to-left

Currently I have to set `rtl=ture` on all widgets that have no RTL parents. How can I set `rtl=ture` for all widgets?

Comment: Please give us your usecase.

Comment: There's an RTL example here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/rtl/rtl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a viewport, simple set `rtl=true` on the Viewport - this is what the [examples](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/rtl/rtl.js) show. However your question indicates that you have distributed widgets in your application.

I don't know of any documented way of doing this for distributed widgets. However, if you have a look at the source code, more specifically for the root object [Ext](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/Ext-more.html) and [Ext.rtl.AbstractComponent](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/source/AbstractComponent2.html), you will find that there is a private default property for this: `Ext.rootHierarchyState.rtl` .

To default your widgets to rtl, set `Ext.rootHierarchyState.rtl = true;` in your initalization code.

Disclaimer: this is marked as a private property, thus not intended for modification, so this solution may easily break between versions of ExtJs.